# How can I get an Ubuntu Phone mounted properly in Ubuntu 15.04? "libmtp error: Could not send object info."

Tags: mount, mtp, aquaris

I get the following error when I try to transfer files to my Ubuntu Phone Aquaris E4.5 by USB:

```
libmtp error:  Could not send object info.
```

It appears to be a problem relating to MTP, but I am neither sufficiently skilled to solve the problem nor am I able to find consistent solutions online to try. I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the installation of the following, no problems were encountered:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libmtpserver-dev mtp-server
```

Comment: Nice self answer :)

Comment: Installed on the phone or your PC?

Comment: The installation was on the computer that was mounting the telephone.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Thanks ! .... and I was cursing MI for making silly phones ! :-D

Comment: Anyone know what this is in focal fossa 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

Today I experienced similar issue, maybe it can help somebody, while copying 711 files, only one had problem and gave `libmtp error:  Could not send object info` error.

Installing various `MTP` packages did not help, I solved problem by renaming the file.

I found out, that the file causing trouble while copying had some upper-case letters and I already had a similar file in target directory with same name but all low-case letters.

```
name of first file.mp3
Name of First File.mp3
```

In Linux file systems like ext4 this would work without any problem, file names are case sensitive and these two would be considered two different files, but this MTP protocol has issues with it throwing the `libmtp error`. I spent hours investigating what's wrong, it was this simple.

Also colon in the file or folder name can be a problem according to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mtp/+bug/1369651).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to another SO answer I gave that might help some people out. https://askubuntu.com/a/886986/523648

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem trying to mount my Samsung Galaxy S6 on my Linux Mint (18.3  Sylvia)  desktop.   I still can't get it working with the AFT application *but* native mtp mounting worked *AFTER* I stopped using my android fast-charging power cable and switched to a generic micro usb cable.