# When installing libmtp: "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status". How to debug/fix?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, compiling, make

Following these instructions for fixing `libmtp` problems ...

https://askubuntu.com/a/886986/296836

... I get these errors ...

```
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_claim_interface'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_string_simple'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_detach_kernel_driver_np'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_descriptor'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_busses'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:506: recipe for target 'mtp-connect' failed
make[2]: *** [mtp-connect] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/mozilla_hasan0/libmtp-1.1.15/examples'
Makefile:526: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/mozilla_hasan0/libmtp-1.1.15'
Makefile:389: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The steps indicated were:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
./configure --prefix=/usr 
make
```

Coming from the JavaScript/Python ecosystem, I have very little experiemce with `make` and `configure`, so any help greatly appreciated.

*Is this an obvious error?
What can I do to track down the cause?*

The full log here below...

---

**Full log:**

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

```
you@tornado:/tmp/mozilla_you0/libmtp-1.1.15$ ./configure --prefix=/usr 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for iconv... yes
checking for working iconv... yes
checking for iconv declaration... 
         extern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
checking for doxygen... false
checking if the host operating system is Darwin... no
checking if the host operating system is Linux... yes
checking For MinGW32... no
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for libusb-1.0 >= 1.0.0... no
checking for openusb_init in -lopenusb... no
checking for libusb >= 0.1.8... no
checking for usb_open in -lusb... yes
checking for libgcrypt... checking for gcry_check_version in -lgcrypt... no
configure: *** libgcrypt not found - disabling MTPZ support ***
configure: MTPZ functionality disable
configure: *** using libusb 0.1 ***
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking ctype.h usability... yes
checking ctype.h presence... yes
checking for ctype.h... yes
checking errno.h usability... yes
checking errno.h presence... yes
checking for errno.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking getopt.h usability... yes
checking getopt.h presence... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking libgen.h usability... yes
checking libgen.h presence... yes
checking for libgen.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking stdio.h usability... yes
checking stdio.h presence... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking byteswap.h usability... yes
checking byteswap.h presence... yes
checking for byteswap.h... yes
checking sys/uio.h usability... yes
checking sys/uio.h presence... yes
checking for sys/uio.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for size_t... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blksize... yes
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... yes
checking whether stat accepts an empty string... no
checking for basename... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strndup... yes
checking for strrchr... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for usleep... yes
checking for mkstemp... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for uint8_t in stdint.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for le32toh in machine/endian.h... no
checking for ntohl in arpa/inet.h... yes
checking for swap32 in machine/endian.h... no
checking for bswap_32 in byteswap.h... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/libmtp.h
config.status: creating doc/Doxyfile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/Makefile
config.status: creating util/Makefile
config.status: creating libmtp.sh
config.status: creating hotplug.sh
config.status: creating libmtp.pc
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
you@tornado:/tmp/mozilla_you0/libmtp-1.1.15$
you@tornado:/tmp/mozilla_you0/libmtp-1.1.15$
```

```
make
```

```
you@tornado:/tmp/mozilla_you0/libmtp-1.1.15$
you@tornado:/tmp/mozilla_you0/libmtp-1.1.15$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/mozilla_hasan0/libmtp-1.1.15'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/mozilla_hasan0/libmtp-1.1.15/src'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-libmtp.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-libmtp.Tpo -c -o libmtp_la-libmtp.lo `test -f 'libmtp.c' || echo './'`libmtp.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-libmtp.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-libmtp.Tpo -c libmtp.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libmtp_la-libmtp.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-libmtp.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-libmtp.Tpo -c libmtp.c -o libmtp_la-libmtp.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libmtp_la-libmtp.Tpo .deps/libmtp_la-libmtp.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-unicode.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-unicode.Tpo -c -o libmtp_la-unicode.lo `test -f 'unicode.c' || echo './'`unicode.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-unicode.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-unicode.Tpo -c unicode.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libmtp_la-unicode.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-unicode.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-unicode.Tpo -c unicode.c -o libmtp_la-unicode.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libmtp_la-unicode.Tpo .deps/libmtp_la-unicode.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-util.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-util.Tpo -c -o libmtp_la-util.lo `test -f 'util.c' || echo './'`util.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-util.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-util.Tpo -c util.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libmtp_la-util.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-util.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-util.Tpo -c util.c -o libmtp_la-util.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libmtp_la-util.Tpo .deps/libmtp_la-util.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-playlist-spl.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-playlist-spl.Tpo -c -o libmtp_la-playlist-spl.lo `test -f 'playlist-spl.c' || echo './'`playlist-spl.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-playlist-spl.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-playlist-spl.Tpo -c playlist-spl.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libmtp_la-playlist-spl.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-playlist-spl.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-playlist-spl.Tpo -c playlist-spl.c -o libmtp_la-playlist-spl.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libmtp_la-playlist-spl.Tpo .deps/libmtp_la-playlist-spl.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-ptp.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-ptp.Tpo -c -o libmtp_la-ptp.lo `test -f 'ptp.c' || echo './'`ptp.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-ptp.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-ptp.Tpo -c ptp.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libmtp_la-ptp.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-ptp.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-ptp.Tpo -c ptp.c -o libmtp_la-ptp.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libmtp_la-ptp.Tpo .deps/libmtp_la-ptp.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-libusb-glue.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-libusb-glue.Tpo -c -o libmtp_la-libusb-glue.lo `test -f 'libusb-glue.c' || echo './'`libusb-glue.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-libusb-glue.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-libusb-glue.Tpo -c libusb-glue.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libmtp_la-libusb-glue.o
libusb-glue.c: In function ‘dump_usbinfo’:
libusb-glue.c:706:7: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   int res;
       ^~~
At top level:
libusb-glue.c:1815:13: warning: ‘clear_halt’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void clear_halt(PTP_USB* ptp_usb)
             ^~~~~~~~~~
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT libmtp_la-libusb-glue.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmtp_la-libusb-glue.Tpo -c libusb-glue.c -o libmtp_la-libusb-glue.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libmtp_la-libusb-glue.Tpo .deps/libmtp_la-libusb-glue.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -no-undefined -export-symbols ./libmtp.sym -version-info 13:0:4   -o libmtp.la -rpath /usr/lib libmtp_la-libmtp.lo libmtp_la-unicode.lo libmtp_la-util.lo libmtp_la-playlist-spl.lo libmtp_la-ptp.lo   libmtp_la-libusb-glue.lo     
libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libmtp.a .libs/libmtp.la .libs/libmtp.lai .libs/libmtp.so .libs/libmtp.so.9 .libs/libmtp.so.9.4.0 .libs/libmtp.ver
libtool: link: echo "{ global:" > .libs/libmtp.ver
libtool: link:  cat ./libmtp.sym | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/\1;/" >> .libs/libmtp.ver
libtool: link:  echo "local: *; };" >> .libs/libmtp.ver
libtool: link:  gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/libmtp_la-libmtp.o .libs/libmtp_la-unicode.o .libs/libmtp_la-util.o .libs/libmtp_la-playlist-spl.o .libs/libmtp_la-ptp.o .libs/libmtp_la-libusb-glue.o    -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libmtp.so.9 -Wl,-version-script -Wl,.libs/libmtp.ver -o .libs/libmtp.so.9.4.0
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libmtp.so.9" && ln -s "libmtp.so.9.4.0" "libmtp.so.9")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libmtp.so" && ln -s "libmtp.so.9.4.0" "libmtp.so")
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libmtp.a  libmtp_la-libmtp.o libmtp_la-unicode.o libmtp_la-util.o libmtp_la-playlist-spl.o libmtp_la-ptp.o libmtp_la-libusb-glue.o
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libmtp.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libmtp.la" && ln -s "../libmtp.la" "libmtp.la" )
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/mozilla_hasan0/libmtp-1.1.15/src'
Making all in examples
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/mozilla_hasan0/libmtp-1.1.15/examples'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../src   -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT connect.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/connect.Tpo -c -o connect.o connect.c
mv -f .deps/connect.Tpo .deps/connect.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../src   -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT delfile.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/delfile.Tpo -c -o delfile.o delfile.c
mv -f .deps/delfile.Tpo .deps/delfile.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../src   -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT getfile.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/getfile.Tpo -c -o getfile.o getfile.c
mv -f .deps/getfile.Tpo .deps/getfile.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../src   -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT newfolder.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/newfolder.Tpo -c -o newfolder.o newfolder.c
mv -f .deps/newfolder.Tpo .deps/newfolder.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../src   -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT sendfile.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/sendfile.Tpo -c -o sendfile.o sendfile.c
mv -f .deps/sendfile.Tpo .deps/sendfile.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../src   -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT sendtr.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/sendtr.Tpo -c -o sendtr.o sendtr.c
mv -f .deps/sendtr.Tpo .deps/sendtr.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../src   -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -MT pathutils.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/pathutils.Tpo -c -o pathutils.o pathutils.c
pathutils.c: In function ‘progress’:
pathutils.c:122:24: warning: format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t {aka const long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("Progress: %llu of %llu (%d%%)\r", sent, total, percent);
                     ~~~^
                     %lu
pathutils.c:122:32: warning: format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘uint64_t {aka const long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("Progress: %llu of %llu (%d%%)\r", sent, total, percent);
                             ~~~^
                             %lu
mv -f .deps/pathutils.Tpo .deps/pathutils.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes   -o mtp-connect connect.o delfile.o getfile.o newfolder.o sendfile.o sendtr.o pathutils.o util.o ../src/libmtp.la 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -o .libs/mtp-connect connect.o delfile.o getfile.o newfolder.o sendfile.o sendtr.o pathutils.o util.o  ../src/.libs/libmtp.so
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_driver_np'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_find_busses'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_release_interface'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_reset'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_clear_halt'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_find_devices'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_set_configuration'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_close'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_device'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_resetep'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_control_msg'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_bulk_write'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_bulk_read'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_init'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_set_debug'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_open'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_claim_interface'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_string_simple'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_detach_kernel_driver_np'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_descriptor'
../src/.libs/libmtp.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_busses'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:506: recipe for target 'mtp-connect' failed
make[2]: *** [mtp-connect] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/mozilla_hasan0/libmtp-1.1.15/examples'
Makefile:526: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/mozilla_hasan0/libmtp-1.1.15'
Makefile:389: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
you@tornado:/tmp/mozilla_you0/libmtp-1.1.15$
```

Comment: It's not obvious to me... however I notice you don't appear to have `pkg-config` and possibly `libusb-dev` and `libusb-1.0-0-dev`. It's a bit of a hail mary but I'd suggest installing all three of those packages and trying again from scratch

Comment: Holy crap!  You're like ... one of those brainTheSizeOfAPlanet androids right?  You should move your comment to be an actual answer, so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: OK thanks! it was pretty much a guess - glad it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is more or less a lucky guess, that just happened to solve the issue.*

---

The two things that jump out from the `./configure` log are:

```
checking for pkg-config... no
```

Although not *necessarily* a problem, `pkg-config` is often used by build systems to locate header files, libraries and link options. It may be that everything necessary to build the software *is* already installed on your system, but the `./configure` script can't find it without the help of `pkg-config`;

and

```
checking for libusb-1.0 >= 1.0.0... no
checking for openusb_init in -lopenusb... no
checking for libusb >= 0.1.8... no
```

which is odd because Ubuntu 18.04 should provide `libusb-1.0-0-dev` version `1.0.21` and `libusb-dev` version `0.1.12` respectively. As noted above, that *may* be because the script can't locate them without the help of `pkg-config`, or may be because the development packages are not yet installed on your system.

Either way, no harm will come from attempting to install all three packages:

```
sudo apt install pkg-config libusb-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

then start over from scratch.